# SED: Inserting an existing pattern, to several other places on the same line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, parsing, sed

Again a SED question from me :)

So, same as last time, I'm wrestling with phone numbers. This time the problem is a bit different. 
I this kind of organization currently in my text file:

```
Areacode:    List of phone numbers:
4444         NUM:111111  NUM:2222222 NUM:33333333
5555         NUM:1111111 NUM:2222    NUM:3333333  NUM:44444444 NUM:5555555
```

Now, every areacode can have unknown number of numbers, and also the phone numbers are not fixed in length. 
What I would like to know, is how could I combine areacode and phone number, to look something like this:

```
4444-111111, 4444-2222222, 4444-33333333
```

My first idea was to add again a line break before each phone number and to match these sections with regex, and then just add the first remembered item to second, and first to third:

```
\1-\2, \1-\3, etc
```

But of course since sed can only remember 9 arguments, and there can be more than 10 numbers in one line this doesn't work. Moreover, also non-fixed list of phone numbers made this a no go. 
I'm again looking primarily the SED option, as I've been trying to get proficient with it - but more efficient solutions with other tools are of course definitely welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt | sed '1d;s/NUM:/ /g' | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf("%s-%s%s", $1, $i, i==NF?"\n":",")}'
4444-111111,4444-2222222,4444-33333333
5555-1111111,5555-2222,5555-3333333,5555-44444444,5555-5555555
```

Comment: Thanks Kev, this does exactly what I asked!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1d;:a;s/^\(\S*\)\(.*\)NUM:/\1\2,\1-/;ta;s/[^,]*,//;s/ //g' file
4444-111111,4444-2222222,4444-33333333
5555-1111111,5555-2222,5555-3333333,5555-44444444,5555-5555555
```

or:

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub(/NUM:/,","$1"-");sub(/[^,]*,/,"");gsub(/ /,"");print}' file
4444-111111,4444-2222222,4444-33333333
5555-1111111,5555-2222,5555-3333333,5555-44444444,5555-5555555
```

Comment: I seem to be getting only the last line as output currently, but that one is correct. I will study your answer to learn what you did there..

Comment: the `1d` and `NR>1` remove the heading line in each solution respectively.

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

```
@(collect)
@area @(coll :mintimes 1)NUM:@{num /[0-9]+/}@(end)
@(output)
@(rep)@area-@num, @(last)@area-@num@(end)
@(end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr phone.txr phone.txt
4444-111111, 4444-2222222, 4444-33333333
5555-1111111, 5555-2222, 5555-3333333, 5555-44444444, 5555-5555555

$ cat phone.txt
Areacode:    List of phone numbers:
4444         NUM:111111  NUM:2222222 NUM:33333333
5555         NUM:1111111 NUM:2222    NUM:3333333  NUM:44444444 NUM:5555555
```